# VBA Macro to remove the duplicates based on column header name

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to Excel VBA I made this macro to remove duplicates based on column name "container". Now there are 2 columns in excel with the name "Container".

```
Sub Remove_DupContainerPOL()

'Removes Duplicate Containers

Dim whs As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, colNumber As Long
Dim colh As String

colh = "Container"
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set whs = Worksheets("POL")
colNumber = Application.Match(colh, whs.Range("A1:AAA1"), 0)

     With whs.Range("A1:AAA" & lRow)
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=colNumber, Header:=xlYes
     End With

End Sub
```

[Original Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0pLU.png)

This is how the columns look like in the excel file. Now when I execute the macro it misbehaves somehow not sure the entire data in preceding rows get shuffled and generates the wrong output.
Is there any way that macro reads the 3 columns i.e. "Container" and only based on that removes duplicates.

Comment: What does *"that macro reads the 3 columns"* mean? If this is happening in one worksheet, then the last row should be determined after the worksheet is defined with `lRow = whs.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`, even better using `xlUp` after `colNumber` has been calculated with `lRow = whs.Cells(whs.Rows.Count,colNumber).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: This means that I am asking ... if you see my screenshot provided in that column named container at first is in 3rd column so only of that third column named container it should remove the duplicates and not loop further to encounter if the excel still has any column with a name/heading "Container".

Comment: Your code works on my end as-is. There's nothing wrong with it except for the inaccuracies mentioned in my previous comment. With `Application.Match` you have set the column number, and it will remove duplicates only 'looking' in this column e.g. if you have several cells containing 1 in the column, it will remove all rows except the first (top) row containing 1.

Comment: I am adding my out put in the question above which is generating wrong output